# Drupal 6: where can I access a form's errors, possibly via form_get_errors(), before outputting the form?

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

As usual, I thought something in the Drupal forms API would be simple... what was I thinking?

**Problem**
I have a block that outputs a form via drupal_get_form().  Somehow in the block's display function, I want to check whether the form failed validation (i.e. has any errors that were set by form_set_error() in my form's validation function).

**Tried so far...**

- checking `$_SESSION['messages']['error']` in block display function - but they are gone by then
- checking `$_POST` in block display function - nothing useful here
- checking `form_get_errors()` in `mymodule_preprocess_page()` - empty
- checking `form_get_errors()` in `mytheme_preprocess_page()` - empty

I am confused by my calls to [form_get_errors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_get_errors/6) being empty.  It calls [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) with no args - which leaves `$reset = FALSE`, thus the static var that holds the form errors does not get cleared.  So I don't know where that var is getting reset - somewhere by another forms api function? - so that by the time I call it in my module or theme, it's empty.

**help?**
So, does anyone know at what point (preprocess functions?) I can call `form_get_errors()` before the static var is cleared?  Or have another idea how to check for form errors in the block that displays the form?  (By the way - I am fairly sure I could check this easily once I am inside my function that `drupal_get_form()` calls... but I need to know about the errors in the enclosing block display function.)

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly as all get out but it should work.

```
$form['#validate'][] = '_error_preservation_helper';

...
function _error_preservation_helper($form, &$form_state) {
  $GLOBALS['_error_preservation_helper'] = form_get_error();
  return true;
}
```